# How to edit a line in a file, replace that line and concatenate(move down) other variables down

Tags: python

I have been trying to figure out in my python code how to replace a line and then change the variables to where it would make sense. For example, below are the variables. If I replace "example_link1" with another "example_link1" the old example link would then need to be "example_link2" and so on with 3, 4, etc.

```
{
    "refId": "example_link1",
    "enabled": true,
    "visible": true
},
{
    "refId": "example_link2",
    "enabled": true,
    "visible": true
}
```

Im a bit new to python so ive been trying to wrap my head around how to do this. This is what i have so far but it is not working correctly at all

```
 with open(publishedjsonfilepath, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.read()

        index = repr(lines).find(find) - 1
        if index < 0:
            raise ValueError("The text was not found in the file!")

        len_found = len(find) - 1
        old_lines = lines[index + len_found:]

        file.seek(index)
        file.write(insert)
        file.write(old_lines)
find_append_to_file()
```

Any help of new code would be appreciated

Comment: if you have JSON then use module `json` to convert it to dictionary, next change values in dictionary, and finally convert it back to JSON. It can be simpler.

Comment: `.read()` gives all text as one string, not list or iterator. Maybe you should use `for line in file:` to work with with every line separatelly. Then you could check line by line.

Comment: if you want to put new link in first place and other move on next places then mayby you should write new link in new file and simply append/copy old file to new file after first link.

Comment: I don't know why you use `repr` for this. And `find()` gives `-1` if it didn't find element so you don't have to use `-1` to check `if index < 0`

Comment: @furas hey thanks I think I know what your saying. Any example of how you would form the code? Having some difficulty on writing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put new link at first place and you can put new `{...}` with all values - `"refId"`, `"enabled"`,
`"visible"` - then you can do

- open for reading,
- read all data,
- close it,
- open for writing,
- write new `{...}`,
- write old data,
- close it.

It can be simpler then moving `link1` in place of `link2` and `link2` in place `link3`, etc.

---

Code

```
new_link = "https://stackoverflow.com"

new_data = f'''{{
   "refId": {new_link},
   "enabled": true,
   "visible": true
}},
'''

with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    old_data = file.read()

with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write(new_data)    
    file.write(old_data)
```

In `f-string` it need `{{` and `}}` to put `{` and `}`

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to put new link between other links then it need different method.

Your variable `publishedjsonfilepath` suggests that you have JSON file - but your example is missing `[ ]` to create correct JSON. But I assume than you have correct JSON file.

I will use string `JSON` instead of file but there will be code which read it.

You could

- read all data as JSON string,
- convert from JSON to list of dictionares,
- use for-loop (with `enumerater` to get number of dictionary) to check every dictionary on the list and compare `item['refId'] == "example_link1"`
- if you find it then you can simply use `list.insert(number, new_data)`. - and then convert it back from list of dictionares to JSON
- and save all again to the same file

Code

```
import json

JSON = '''[
{
    "refId": "example_link0",
    "enabled": true,
    "visible": true
},
{
    "refId": "example_link1",
    "enabled": true,
    "visible": true
},
{
    "refId": "example_link2",
    "enabled": true,
    "visible": true
}
]'''

new_link = "https://stackoverflow.com"

new_data = {
   "refId": new_link,
   "enabled": True,
   "visible": True
}

#with open(filename, 'r') as file:
#    JSON = file.read()

data = json.loads(JSON)

searched = "example_link1"

for number, item in enumerate(data):
    if item['refId'] == searched:
        print('found:', number)
        data.insert(number, new_data)
        break
else:  # it is `for/else`, not `if/else
    print('not found')         

JSON = json.dumps(data, indent=2)        
print(JSON)

#with open(filename, 'w') as file:
#    file.write(JSON)
```

I used (not so popular) `for/else` to run code if `break` wasn't use inside `for`-loop.

Comment: awesome thanks! Makes sense. one more question, once it finds the link I am looking for and then replaces it with the new link (For example link1 gets replaced by a new link1) how could i change the old link to link2. To be more specific each link is connected to a url, and it appears at the top depending on the link number. So if i replace link1 with a new link1 that old link would have to move down and become link2, 3, etc... If that makes sense

Comment: do you really have to move only link to next place? Can't you move full `{...}` to next place? I insert new link before old link so old `{...}` automatically move to next place. If you have to mov only link (without moving also `enable, visible` then you would have to use another `for`-loop to move new to old - but first you would have to get previous value from this place and move it next place below. It would be simpler to get second from the end and put on last place, next get third from the end and put on second from the end, etc until uou get from place `number` to `number+`